# Set a ResourceDictionary DataContext from code behind

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I'm trying to set a ResourceDictionary DataContext, from the code behind of my Resource Dictionary.

I have a Data Template that uses its own style (the Resource Dictionary), the style contains a checkbox with its own style :

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="CheckBox_Checked"/>
    <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Unchecked" Handler="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>        
</Style>
```

In the CheckBox_Checked event, I want to reference the dictionary's parent (a User Control) View Model, to execute a function, but because Resource Dictionaries do not have a DataContext property setting the DataContext from inside a control event, like this :

```
    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {  
      MyViewModel viewModel = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
    }
```

doesn't work (of course).

I think I need to get a handle to the Ancestor (the Resource Dictionary User Control), but don't know how to do this - or there may be another way..

Thanks

Joe

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Post some sample code, yeah?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Of course ResourceDictionaries don't have a DataContext, they are not controls in any way you can't use DataBinding. A ResourceDictionary is, well like the name says, just a Dictionary of Resources identified by Key. What might be confusing is that UserControl and Windows have a XAML file and you might get these XAMLs mixed up with XAMLs just describing ResourceDictionaries. But they are pretty different. A XAML doesn't mean its a ResourceDictionary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @dowhilefor's comment says, Resource Dictionaries are simply a collection of resources, so do not need a DataContext. You can, however, add a code-behind file to the ResourceDictionary, which may be what you're looking for.

Create a new class in the same directory as your `ResourceDictionary` and name it ResourceDictionaryName.xaml.cs. It will become the code-behind file for your `ResourceDictionary`.

Open the new .cs file, and make sure the following is there (Can't remember if it's added automatically or not):

```
public partial class ResourceDictionaryName
{
    public ResourceDictionaryName()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Next, open your XAML file and add the following `x:Class` attribute to the `ResourceDictionary` Tag:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="MyNamespace.ResourceDictionaryName" ... />
```

Now your `ResourceDictionary` is actually a class, and can have a code-behind file.

**Edit**

In response to your edits, I would use the CheckBox itself and get either the CheckBox's DataContext, or traverse up the Visual Tree to find the UserControl I'm looking for and then get it's Data Context

Easy way:

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    var cbx = sender as CheckBox;
    MyViewModel viewModel = (MyViewModel)cbx.DataContext;
}
```

If CheckBox's DataContext is not the ViewModel you're looking for:

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    var cbx = sender as CheckBox;
    var userControl = FindAncestor<MyUserControl>(cbx);
    MyViewModel viewModel = (MyViewModel)myUserControl.DataContext;
}

public static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject current)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);

    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current is T)
        {
            return (T)current;
        }
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    };
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rachel - yes thats exactly what I'm doing - but then how can I reference the parent (user control's) View Model? (please see amended question.

Comment: Usually I use `(sender as CheckBox).DataContext` to get the ViewModel, or if the DataContext is not the ViewModel, I would get the CheckBox reference (`sender`), then traverse up the visual tree until I find an object of of type `MyUserControl` and get it's DataContext. See the edit to my answer

Comment: InitializeComponent(); method is not found in this approach. 
please help. Do I need to inherit this class from some Control?

Comment: @deathrace Does your XAML include the `x:Class` attribute? If you're having trouble with it, you'd be best off posting a new question with the details of your situation.

Comment: I have a new question, if anyone from this thread is willing to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018071/wpf-binding-resourcedictionary-source-to-a-resourcedictionary-property-of-the-presenter-or-datacontext